# Is there a way to add a color scale legend in a gt table R?

Tags: r, gt

I have a gt() table in a quarto document in which cells are color filled based on their value. I would like to know if it is possible to add a color legend scale, like in a ggplot.

Thanks,
Pedro

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a small GT table above your table that requires a legend.

[image: Sample]

```
{r}
library(gt)
df <- data.frame(Lessthan5 = 'Less than 5', 
                 Equalto5 = 'Equal to 5', 
                 GreaterThan5 = 'Grater than 5') %>% 
  gt() %>% 
    tab_style(style = cell_fill(color = '#eeca87'), 
            locations = cells_body(columns=c(Lessthan5), 
                                   rows = Lessthan5 == 'Less than 5')) %>% 
  tab_style(style = cell_fill(color = '#c5c5c5'), 
            locations = cells_body(columns=c(Equalto5), 
                                   rows = Equalto5 == 'Equal to 5'))  %>% 
  tab_style(style = cell_fill(color = '#4EB89B'), 
            locations = cells_body(columns=c(GreaterThan5), 
                                   rows = GreaterThan5 == 'Grater than 5')) %>% 
  tab_options(column_labels.font.size = 0)

{r}
library(gt)

iris %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  tab_style(style = cell_fill(color = '#eeca87'), 
            locations = cells_body(columns=c(Sepal.Length), 
                                   rows = Sepal.Length < 5)) %>% 
  tab_style(style = cell_fill(color = '#c5c5c5'), 
            locations = cells_body(columns=c(Sepal.Length), 
                                   rows = Sepal.Length == 5))  %>% 
  tab_style(style = cell_fill(color = '#4EB89B'), 
            locations = cells_body(columns=c(Sepal.Length), 
                                   rows = Sepal.Length > 5))
```

Comment: I was expecting/hoping something built-in, but that surely works.
Thanks a lot Susan!